# Can you extract the current learning rate from tf.keras.Adam?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I want to experiment with decay during training, using Tensorflow's keras implementation and Adam. It appears that *model.optimizer.lr* is the base learning rate only and does not change with decay.  For monitoring and visualization, it would be reassuring to see the actual value in use.  Can it be obtained directly (without calculating it in parallel and assuming you are doing you math right)?

Comment: The base learning rate is always constant. you need to write a callback function and `on_epoch_end()` calculate the current learning rate according to your optimizer formula.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code. This is adapted from the Keras source code. I have not tested it myself.

```
class AdamLearningRateTracker(Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, logs={}):
        beta_1 = self.beta_1, 
        beta_2 = self.beta_2
        optimizer = self.model.optimizer
        if optimizer.decay > 0:
            lr = K.eval(optimizer.lr * (1. / (1. + optimizer.decay * optimizer.iterations)))
        t = K.cast(optimizer.iterations, K.floatx()) + 1
        lr_t = lr * (K.sqrt(1. - K.pow(beta_2, t)) /(1. - K.pow(beta_1, t)))
        print('lr: {:.6f}\n'.format(lr_t))
```

Comment: This is what I meant by "calculating it in parallel and assuming you are doing you math right".  You are basically using a duplicate copy of the learning rate update code inside Adam in order to be able to, essentially, run the same code twice. Maybe this is the only way to do it, but it doesn't give that real confidence that the actual learning rate is behaving as expected.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. This is duplicating the same code. I haven't come across any different way of doing it though. Let's hope there is a better way. :)

Comment: Does anyone know why it is so difficult to extract this? Why isnt there a generic function for this?